# No "Common Data Service" API option Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, common-data-service

I need to add the "Common Data Service" API in my Azure account in order to implement an integration to Dynamics 365.
[However, it is not listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh26C.png)

Also, the following error appears during my attempt to connect to Azure:

```
The app needs access to a service (\"https://api.ci.ai.dynamics.com\") that your organization \"my_organization_id\" has not subscribed to or enabled.
```

As far as I understand, I need to subscribe\enable to https://api.ci.ai.dynamics.com\, right? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

No expert on the topic but based on [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/walkthrough-register-app-azure-active-directory), it should be available as `Microsoft APIs > Dynamics CRM > Delegated Permissions > user_impersonation`.

I still find it in the same place as below

> [image: add-permission-blade-microsoft-apis]
>
> [image: add-permission-blade-dynamics-crm-user-impersonation]

Comment: There is no Common data service :)